# Styling a button from a separate css file

Tags: html, css

i'd like to style buttons in some html code that is linked to a css file. The style for the buttons is in the css file.

Everything else works, but when I try to get the styled button, it turns into a normal html button unless the style is defined in the html file.

The HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' id='button' class="button" value='Button' onclick='AddOne()'>
    (function defined here, works correctly)
</body>
</html>
```

The stylesheet:

```
.button {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #535362;
}
```

If I add the style with the style tag in the html file itself, it works. But I don't want to paste a block of style code into the file every time I need a button, else why bother with css altogether?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with giving correct location of css file wrt. html file. Can you provide the location you are using after moving css into same folder as html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow _

Your CSS doesn't have 'button' as a class _ the code should look like this

```
.button {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #535362;
}
```

Here's the snippet >>>

```css
.button {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #535362;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type='button' id='button' class="button" value='Button' onclick='AddOne()'>
    (function defined here, works correctly)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and quick reply! I've added the dots to make the button a class, but the button still shows as a normal html button. :(

Comment: It works fine for me. Have you checked that you are linking to the file correctly (i.e., is "/static/css/main.css" correct?

Comment: I concur with @AdamK _ the code is working for me as well _ So the issue is probably caused by the link to the CSS

Comment: You are right, there seems to be something wrong. I've renamed the css file to see if the site would change, it does not. I can't find the file it's using. :/

Comment: Try putting the `main.css` file in the same folder as your `html` file and redirect the link to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />`

Comment: Alternatively_ try removing the first slash from the current 'href' _ hence `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/main.css" />`

Comment: It is not working. I changed the filename to main2.css and moved it into the same folder as the html and changed the link accordingly. It's not finding it, but it's finding main.css, even though there are no more files with that name.

Comment: hmm _ flush browser cache?

Comment: Done, no change, except now its not taking any css file. I am so confused right now. For reference, I'm using bottle and the html file is a template.

Comment: I don't know what "bottle" is _ sorry I can't be more help : \ _ The only other suggestion I can make is whether its possible to rebuild basic steps of both files outside of the template in a new folder

Comment: Thank you, inputforcolor. I tried making a fresh html with the old css file and that's not using it either. They're in the same folder and I'm sure I linked it correctly. Nothing is working, maybe the API is broken somehow? None of the html files can link to any css, even the old sites which worked a few weeks ago, everyone here is confused includig me. I'm done. :/

Comment: Sorry to hear that _ Perhaps it is the API _ Connect with support people at the source _ Maybe they can help _ Don't give up_ you'll get there _ Good Luck ; )

Comment: Quick update, when I go onto the site and press Ctr U and click on the css link, I get the html version of the 404 not found site. I'm sure the link is correct, I checked it 10 times. Could there be some kind of permissions issue?

Comment: Just to clarify @GuardianAngel02 _ is the site you're referring to the source of the API you mentioned? Or do you mean your own site? Also_ when you said HTML file is a template_ do you mean unconnected code you could download or copy / paste _ or is it a template connected to something else_ like a web-host (Wix - 123-reg etc)?

Comment: So bottle is a very basic python based web framework (like flask but cheaper). I'm making my own site to familiarize myself with html and js and accessing it through a browser using localhost. I just realised bottle opens a console and documents the events. Apparently, if I put in a fresh copy of my css file and start the server file, it finds the css file and applies it. But when I try to edit the css file (changing color for example), it doesn't update and instead loses the link (I see this error 404 in the console) and when I clear the browser cache and reload the page,it's without the css.

Comment: It's strange because back when I worked with the framework before, I had no problems and could update the css file and see the changes live after reloading the page.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about Python @GuardianAngel02 _ I just looked through Stack Exchange to see if there's a dedicated Python page but unfortunately not _ Perhaps a new question with Python in the title?
Sorry I can't help further _ Good Luck

Comment: Be sure to go to SO Help Center and check out 'Asking' section before you set the question _ Contributors will want to look at code

Comment: I think I'll do just that, thank you @inputforcolor :)

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer @GuardianAngel02 _ Your points just got me promoted on SO! o: ) Take Care